# Email spam protection script

Tags: email, captcha, spam

I have a small real estate virtual tour website where visitors can email the agent asking for information.

I realize I need to protect the email form to prevent spamming my agents.

I would like to avoid those awful image captcha's like reCAPTCHA.
Are there any other options? Like a very simple math question, without having to render an image with GD? Something like: "2 + 3 = ?"
I was thinking math's because I have a multi language website and like I don't have to translate strings etc.

What about a time protection? I think I saw this before. You need to wait x seconds before sending a second email. Maybe because off some "hammering" scripts?

Any links or lights appreciated!

**EDIT** Forgot to say, I am sending the data with AJAX (jQuery), so there is no real form to submit..

Comment: Some of the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4683117/507519) might be useful to you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) If you'd like to place email address on the page - you can encode it, so it will be invisible to crawlers.

You can use this tool to do that:
http://www.artshipulin.com/stuff/email-address-to-html-entities.php

2) That's a useful article on captchas:
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/04/in-search-of-the-perfect-captcha/

Answer (score 0):

Just a note. Spam is getting more intelligent and will often use different IP's to attack your forms so time protection would reduce same IP spamming but you may also want to check for unwanted content like urls, bbcode, html etc. You can use math equations but these are simple to break quite quickly for a spammer.

Captcha's are widely used because they are simple, yet effective. Generally, a worded question would be more effective than a math equation (add nine and four rather than 9+4) but seeing as translation is an issue, your not left with many choices.

even a "click the black square" style human validation would need you to translate the instruction but obviously involves less work than worded questions. This works by randomly placing around 5 squares of different colours and getting the user to click a specific one. This would need javascript which also helps prevent spammers because they don't render the page. They look at raw source

Comment: Actually I am using Javascript to send the form with AJAX. That's why I thought a math equation might be enough. I found one here: http://www.codegravity.com/projects/mathguard But can't find v2.0 off this script which I prefer.

Comment: It seems like it would do the trick. You may as well use version 3.3. I see it works differently but remember that over the different versions, bug fixes and security holes get fixed. It's best to use the latest stable versions.